# Calculating Expectation using the Linearity of Expectation law and sum of indicator random variables

Tags: expected-value, categorical-encoding, linearity

I'm attempting to complete the problem sets for the Stanford CS109 Statistics course from 2021 as I follow along with the lectures.

I'm stuck on a particular problem in one of these problem sets. I have two answers, but they don't agree. Here's the question:

*You have 8 pairs of mittens, each a different color. Left and right mittens are distinct. Suppose that you are fostering (possibly imaginary) kittens, and you leave them alone for a few hours with your mittens. When you return, you discover that they have hidden 4 mittens! Suppose that your kittens are equally likely to hide any 4 of your 16 distinct mittens. Let $X$ be the number of complete, distinct pairs of mittens that you have left.



(a) Compute the probability mass function of $X$, $p_x(k)$.

(b) Find $E[X]$ using your answer to part (a) and the definition of expectation.

(c) Find $E[X]$ again, but using linearity of expectation this time and indicator RVs.*

There is obviously a bit of interpretation involved in answering this question, which could of course be a source of error.

### Parts (a) and (b)

I began with these (maybe wrongful) observations:

- The handedness of a mitt doesn't matter, nor does its colour. All that matters for the integrity of a pair is whether none, one or both of the mitts have been hidden.
- If neither mitt has been hidden, the pair is intact. Otherwise, it's not.
- With 4 mitts hidden, at most 4 pairs can be affected, which means *at least* 4 pairs will remain intact in all circumstances.

We can consider only the 4 pairs that may be affected, and add in the 4 unaffected pairs to adjust the values of X in our PMF afterwards. I made this diagram to help me think about the branching probabilities:
[image: branching_probabilities]

$S_i$ denotes the state after the ith mitt-hiding event. Each vertical pair of 2 dots represents the two mitts of a pair. A mitt either belongs to a complete pair (blue), or a pair with one mitt already missing (green). Pairs are rearranged wlog so that pairs with a missing mitt come first. Since each mitt has an equal likelihood of being hidden, we can compute the cumulative probabilities of arriving at each of the subsequent states after the next mitt is hidden.

The number in red is the probability of arriving at a configuration through all of the possible paths; the number in brackets afterwards is the share of probability that led to this state from the state's parent. Sometimes two different parent states can lead to the same child state (such as the first two configurations in $S_3$), in which case we sum their probabilities. A second number in brackets indicates this sum.

Following this through we can see that we arrive at either 6 remaining pairs (2 plus the 4 unaffected), 5 pairs, or 4 pairs. All other values for $X$ have probability 0.

And so, our PMF is

| $x$ | $P(X=x)$ |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | $\frac{24}{105}$ |
| 5 | $\frac{72}{105}$ |
| 6 | $\frac{9}{105}$ |

with all other probabilities being zero. From this, we calculate $E[X]$ to be
$$4\cdot\frac{24}{105} + 5\cdot\frac{72}{105} + 6\cdot\frac{9}{105}$$

which is $4.86$ (3sf).

### Part (c)

Part (c) wishes us to rethink the question in terms of indicator random variables. Again, my reasoning may be off here:

Let $L$ be the event that neither mitt of a pair was hidden after 4 rounds of hiding, and let $I_L$ be its indicator random variable. Then, the expectation of the indicator random is the probability of $L$ and is the same for each of the 8 pairs:

$$E[I_L] = P(L) = \frac{14}{16}\cdot\frac{13}{15}\cdot\frac{12}{14}\cdot\frac{11}{13} = 0.55$$

In the first round of hiding, 14 of the 16 mitts are unrelated to the pair. After 1 is hidden, 13 of the remaining 15 mitts don't belong to the pair, and so on. Thus, to make it through intact the probability is $0.55$ exactly.

The Expectation of X, $E[X]$, should then be equal to the sum of the expectations of these indicator random variables. Since there are 8 pairs, this would lead to
$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{8}I_L = 8\cdot0.55 = 4.4$$

While somewhat close, this answer is clearly distinct from my answer in part b.), so I'm wondering - which of the two (if either) is correct, and what would the mistake in my reasoning be in the other?